# Open 3 different google searches by one click

Tags: javascript, onclick

I´m looking for a way to run three google searches with three different keywords by one click.

Here´s what I got so far:

```
<form action="https://google.com/search" method="get" target="_blank">
<input type="text" id="q1" name="q" placeholder="first" required /><br>
<input type="text" id="q2" name="q" placeholder="second" required /><br>
<input type="text" id="q3" name="q" placeholder="third" required /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Google Search" />
</form>
```

It opens a new tab with a google search for all three keywords. 
But I want it to open three different tabs/sites/frames... each one with a search for one keyword. I guess there´s a way to solve this problem with js but I know almost nothing about java script. 
I need something like:
onsubmit = window.open("search1"); window.open("search2"); window.open("search3");

Hope you can help me.

Greetz

Comment: see my answer and let me know if it helped

Answer (score 0):

```js
function openNewTab(url){
  var redirectWindow = window.open(url, '_blank');
    redirectWindow.location;
}
document.getElementById("asd").addEventListener("click", submit);
function submit(){
var a = document.getElementById('q1').value;
var b = document.getElementById('q2').value;
var c = document.getElementById('q3').value;
var url = "http://google.com/search?q=";
 openNewTab(url+a);
 openNewTab(url+b);
 openNewTab(url+c);

}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" id="q1" name="q" placeholder="first" required /><br>
<input type="text" id="q2" name="q" placeholder="second" required /><br>
<input type="text" id="q3" name="q" placeholder="third" required /><br>
<input type="submit" id="asd" value="Google Search" />
</form>
```

Well this is entirely based on user's browser settings whether he allows to open new tabs by scripts or not. Above code will only work if Popups are allowed in browser. I see no other way to sort it out

To test on your browser (Assume you're running `chrome`) , you can change settings here `chrome://settings/content/popups` in your browser and allow popups

Answer (score 0):

I´ve got a solution... not very elegant but it works (sort of).

```
<form id="form1" action="https://google.com/search" method="get" target="_blank">
   <input type="text" id="q1" name="q" placeholder="first" required /></form><br>
<form id="form2" action="https://google.com/search" method="get" target="_blank">
   <input type="text" id="q2" name="q" placeholder="second" required /></form><br>
<form id="form3" action="https://google.com/search" method="get" target="_blank">
   <input type="text" id="q3" name="q" placeholder="third" required /></form><br>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit();
document.getElementById('form2').submit();
document.getElementById('form3').submit();"> Search </button>
```